# mogoose transaction is not working with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Code

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const sesion = await mongoose.startSession();

  try {
    sesion.startTransaction();
    const blog = new Blog({ title: "blog title" });
    const byte = new Dsabytes({ topStory: "Not an ObjectId" });
    await blog.save();
    await byte.save(); // throw an error, because topStory should be an ObjectId

    await sesion.commitTransaction();
    sesion.endSession();
    res.send("OK");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    await sesion.abortTransaction();
    sesion.endSession();
    res.status(500).send(e.toString());
  }
});
```

In the Dsabytes schema,I have defined `topStory` to be an `ObjectId`. When I run the above code with `topStory:"6167213f5003f3d062dd833f"` then it's working fine.

But, when `await byte.save()` throws an error then ideally `sesion.abortTransaction()` should remove the update caused by `blog.save()`.

### Database before API call

#### Blogs

```js
[]
```

#### Dsabytes

```js
[]
```

### DB after API call

#### Blogs

```js
[
{
  title:"blog title"
}
]
```

#### Dsabytes

```js
[]
```

So, when it throws an error then both collections should be empty at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to pass the session on save

something like that

```
await blog.save({ session });
await byte.save({ session });
```